# Issue when trying to get the chromedriver using selenium-webdriver in Intelij with Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, runtime-error

I moved my folder from my PC to my Macbook PRO, with all dependencies and everything else and when I try to run my tests I get this error below.
I want to point out that I reimported dependencies, I even started to create a new project and I still have the same error, I watched a lot of tutorials to get to the bottom of this but I can't.
I selected the path where the chromedriver is located I even added it to the bin folder in MAC.
I'm using inteliJ with JDK 11.

At line 11 : WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
I'm getting this console error below.

This is the code :

```
package com.qa.testing;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/Popita/Downloads/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();



    }
}
```

Errors:

````
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'abc', ip: 'ab12', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '11.6.2', java.version: '11.0.14'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
remote stacktrace: 0   chromedriver                        0x000000010760fee9 chromedriver + 5013225
1   chromedriver                        0x000000010759b1d3 chromedriver + 4534739
2   chromedriver                        0x0000000107171a68 chromedriver + 170600
3   chromedriver                        0x000000010719149c chromedriver + 300188
4   chromedriver                        0x000000010718f756 chromedriver + 292694
5   chromedriver                        0x00000001071c9550 chromedriver + 529744
6   chromedriver                        0x00000001071c36d3 chromedriver + 505555
7   chromedriver                        0x000000010719976e chromedriver + 333678
8   chromedriver                        0x000000010719a745 chromedriver + 337733
9   chromedriver                        0x00000001075cbefe chromedriver + 4734718
10  chromedriver                        0x00000001075e5a19 chromedriver + 4839961
11  chromedriver                        0x00000001075eb1c8 chromedriver + 4862408
12  chromedriver                        0x00000001075e63aa chromedriver + 4842410
13  chromedriver                        0x00000001075c0a01 chromedriver + 4688385
14  chromedriver                        0x0000000107601538 chromedriver + 4953400
15  chromedriver                        0x00000001076016c1 chromedriver + 4953793
16  chromedriver                        0x0000000107617225 chromedriver + 5042725
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff2057c8fc _pthread_start + 224
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff20578443 thread_start + 15 ```

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at com.qa.testing.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:11)

Process finished with exit code 1


Image of error:

[error1][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0BMf.png
````

Answer (score 0):

1. based on the error, make sure you have Chrome installed
2. make sure the file `/Users/Popita/Downloads/chromedriver` fits to Chrome version
3. clean and rebuild your project

Comment: 1. Chrome is installed 2. the version fits with .102 at the end of it as in the chrome browser 3. I   already created a new project and still get this.

Answer (score 0):

Chromedriver versions must be maintained in sync with the current version of chrome installed.

Comment: The version is the same with the browser : 98.0.4758.102

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary` - looks like it can't even find your chrome.

Comment: If you think you can help me somehow with this issue, maybe you can "take the wheel" and hop on my laptop with teamviewer and you can play with it until maybe you'll find a solution, i'm honestly beaten.

Comment: You probably need to have maven (or whatever build system you're using) set the PATH env variable.